# Deploying create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

After **npm run build**, i upload *build* folder to github, it doesn't work.

[Check this link](https://azad56789980.github.io/myapp/)
[GitHub](https://github.com/azad56789980/myapp)

Why?

Comment: Check the developer console in your browser. You have 404 errors for both your javascript and your css.

Comment: I used create-react-app and then just run npm run build. Didn't change any code in it. Why it gives error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [this](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages) and it will work.

Demo: https://azad56789980.github.io/myapp2/

GitHub: https://github.com/azad56789980/myapp2/